# Payslips for assistant in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, sole-proprietorship

I operate as a sole trader. I have an assistant that I pay on a regular basis.

Do I need to provide them with payslips? If so, what information is legally required to be shown on the payslip other than the amount of pay (it is a small payment, not enough to exceed their tax/NI allowances)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**People who work don’t have the right to a payslip if they’re:**

- not an employee, eg contractors, freelancers or ‘workers’ - read
  about the different types of employment status
- in the police service
- a merchant seaman
- master or crew member working in share fishing (paid by a share in
  the profits or gross earnings of a fishing vessel)

Payslips must show earnings before and after any deductions, explain any deductions and show how the wage is paid.

**Deductions**

Employers must explain any fixed deductions from a person’s wages, eg trade union subscriptions. They must do this either on a payslip, or in a separate written statement.

This separate statement must be sent out before the first payslip. Employers must update this every year.

Apart from any legal deductions like tax or National Insurance, employers can’t make any deductions from wages unless either:

- they’re in the employment contract
- the employee has said in writing that they accept the deduction before it’s made

Have you applied or have a PAYE Employer reference ? If you are a sole trader I would assume you might be having one. You would need that to pay employer NI contributions if any.

There are free payroll software provided by HMRC, use one of those to generate payslips. When you set it up you will be asked for all the information you need to generate payslips.

Comment: Ok, great, thanks for the information. The assistant is not an employee in the legal sense of the term, so I don't need to worry about pay slips.

Comment: When you say they're not an employee in the legal sense of the term, do they fit the HMRC definition of "self-employed" instead?

Comment: Either self-employed or 'worker' I would say - they have no contract, they decide their own hours of work, they receive a set amount regardless of the time taken to complete the work, and they only perform the work if the work is there to be performed - which depends entirely on my own output.

Comment: @danwellman Here is the different employment status from HMRC. They generally ask you to call if you are unsure. https://www.gov.uk/employment-status/overview